# What is a semantic open database

Tags: database

I read an article on a website and it mentioned something about semantic open databases. I tried googling this term but could not determine what the term meant. Here is the article here:

http://wiki.creativecommons.org/Grants/SocialCompare

> - new data created from scratch to motivate users to do the same thing.
> - a tool to import data from external open existing databases (such as
>     semantic open databases).
> - the translations of the website interface or some open data in several
>     languages to be used worldwide more
>     easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked at an R&D company that worked on a [semantic web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web) data store, and I've never heard that specific term, "semantic open database."  I assume it was made up by the authors of the proposal you linked to.

Perhaps they mean any source of semantic data using open standards like [RDF](http://www.w3.org/standards/techs/rdf#w3c_all) and [OWL](http://www.w3.org/standards/techs/owl#w3c_all).  Their grant proposal is pretty vague.

Have you considered [contacting the authors](http://socialcompare.com/en/legal) to ask what they meant?

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I wll do just that